# Como salvar um arquivo de upload no banco com Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Pesquisei um pouco sobre upload de arquivos com primefaces e não encontrei nenhum exemplo de código que salvasse um arquivo no banco.

Dá pra salvar um arquivo como se ele fosse um atributo de uma classe?

Answer (score 0):

Dá sim, vc tem que salvar um byte array do arquivo. Usei no exemplo abaixo o componente do primefaces (http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml) como referencia:

Entidade:

`public class Pessoa {
    private Integer idPessoa;
    private String nome;
    private byte[] foto;
    //get e set
}`

ManagedBean:

`@ManagedBean(name = "pessoaMB")
@SessionScoped
public class PessoaMB {
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    private StreamedContent foto;
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        this.pessoa = new Pessoa();
    }
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        try {
            this.pessoa.setFoto(event.getFile().getContents());
            this.foto = new DefaultStreamedContent(event.getFile().getInputstream());
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Sucesso", event.getFile().getFileName() + " foi carregada.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }
    public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }
    public StreamedContent getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho nunca salvar byte array em banco de dados, no futuro caso precise fazer um backup seu banco estará enorme, em vez disso utilize soluções como S3 da amazon, trabalhamos dessa forma em diversas soluções e sempre foi a melhor escolha adotada.

a mudança de código será simples, ao invez de jogar em uma entidade crie um serviço que salve o arquivo na S3, e ai salve o link gerado no seu cadastro.